# Replacing Foreign Key with Reference Name from other table in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS matrix report in which Loans are mapped with primary keys of Employees originated the loan, so the tables looks like:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>LoanID</td><td>Employee</td></tr><tr><td>101</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>102</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>103</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>104</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>105</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>106</td><td>2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Employeeid</td><td>Employee Name</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>C</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

When I create the matrix using first table I get:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Employee</td><td>Count Of Loans</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

But I wanted result like:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><td>Employee</td><td>Count of Loans</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>C</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

How can I relate the name of values in rows groups to take out the names of Employees?

Answer (score 0):

It is generally better to join tables in the source system when you can. To answer your question, you can use the `Lookup` function to get the Employee Name from the second dataset. In this case it would look something like this:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Employee.Value, Fields!EmployeeID.Value, Fields!EmployeeName.Value, "DataSet2")
```

In other words, for each row, it is looking up the employee ID in the second dataset and returning the name.